# En dash character replaced with a question mark (Ajax call)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, encoding

I'm making a standard jQuery `$.ajax()` call, doing a POST. The call passes a string to PHP controller.

The problem is the following: when a **[en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)** (–) character is used in the string, by the time it reaches PHP it's replaced with a (?) character. A normal hyphen (-) does not cause the problem.

The site's encoding is UTF-8. I'm not sure how to get around this problem. I probably could do some character replacing, but then do I need to do it for every single "problematic" punctuation mark?

And the problem aside, shouldn't this just *work* if the encoding is correct?

Confusing.

**Update:**

I used `mb_detect_encoding()` on the passed string. The result is "ASCII"... I'm working with a legacy code. How do I fix something like that?

Comment: What about PHP script encoding? `The site's encoding is UTF-8.` Do you mean both HTML page and PHP are UTF8 encoded?

Comment: do a urldecode on the string from the ajax

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yep, the PHP script is utf-8 as well.

Comment: @madalinivascu The string gets saved into the DB. What should be done with after I urldecode it? I still want the dash in the string. Just need to prevent switching it to a question mark.

Comment: the ajax urlencodes the data before it sends it to the server,you need to decode it to get the initial value from the browser

Answer (score 0):

On PHP side, the `$_REQUEST` global was used to retrieve the Ajax data. After I changed it to `$_POST`, the en dashes are kept.

I don't really get why `$_REQUEST` was failing, though.

Anyway, this worked in this case. I truly dislike the devs who wrote this code and created this project :)